# Germany-Specific: Unerlaubte Rechtsberatung

Tags: discussion

what is the position of the workplace community on "unerlaubte Rechtsberatung" (giving legal advice for a specific legal situation to a person may get you fined unless you are a lawyer or acting in a similar function).

https://www.wbs-law.de/internetrecht/betreiber-einer-selbsthilfe-website-wegen-unerlaubter-rechtsberatung-verurteilt-45495/

Regards,
   Sascha

Comment: "_The court ruled that these specific statements regarding the statute of limitations constitute unlawful legal advice. The user who made these statements demonstrably did not have permission for such legal information. After the operator of the forum had refused to erase the statements of the user, he was personally held responsible for the illegal legal advice._"

Comment: Asking for [legal advice](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is off topic (it's even off topic on [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) ("Communications on Law Stack Exchange are not privileged communications and do not create an attorney-client relationship.")). Doesn't that already cover it?

Comment: If you have concerns over legal matters, including legal validity or liability of advice given on this site, we would likely refer you to the Contact page where you can reach out to the Community Management team. Beyond that @AnneDaunted's comment is essentially correct in that we never claim to give legal advice here and none of the answers should be seen to constitute legal advice for specific situations.